# Where to put helper functions of a functional component ? what's best for performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The place we put our helpers in a functional component would affect the performance of the component ... I mean what's better when it comes to performance ... to put it outside or inside the component?

```
const onPress = () => {}; // here

const MyComponent = () => {
  const onPress = () => {}; // < or here
  return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={onpress}>...</TouchableOpacity>);
};
```

Comment: It does not matter, your code is eventually uglified/minified into a single file anyways.

Comment: If you can get away with creating the function outside of the component, then that will be more efficient in that a new function will not be created every render. Most of the time though, you need to do something specific to the component that can be impossible to do with a function outside of the component. For most cases the performance difference will be negligible.

Comment: Outside it is more performant. But that does not matter. What matters is: Which code makes more sense to *you*?

Comment: @Igr ... will the helper functions be created each time the functional component is called ... in case I chose to put them inside the component?

Comment: @Tholle & Jonas ... that was exactly what I thought about ... regarding what makes sense for me ...is the option that would be more performant :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can get away with creating the function outside of the component, then that will be more efficient in that a new function will not be created every render.

Most of the time though, you need to do something specific to the component that can be impossible to do with a function outside of the component. For most cases the performance difference will be negligible.